# How does calculate xA=B by hand?

Tags: matrices, matlab

When input [1,5,-3] / [3,2,-2] in MATLAB, the output is 1.1176, which is the least squares solution. How can I do this calculation by hand?

Comment: For $Ax=B$, find $A^{-1}$ if it exists and then $x=BA^{-1}$

Comment: But A is not a square matrix which is not invertible. How do I proceed?

Comment: I think what you may be looking for is the pseudo-inverse. Perhaps the formulae here can help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse

Comment: In your particular case you might use $(A^T A)^{-1}A^T$ or $A^T(AA^T)^{-1}$.

Comment: That works, thanks!!